# Is this code valid or not? GCC and Clang disagree

Tags: c++11, gcc, clang, initializer-list

The following code gives me different results on GCC and Clang. Who's right?

```
union Foo {
    struct {
        int a;
        int b;
    };
};

struct Bar {
    Bar(void) : test{.a = 1, .b = 2} { }
    Foo test;
};
```

I get the following error with GCC (and it compiles fine with Clang):

```
arcanis@/tmp # g++ -std=c++11 x.cpp 
x.cpp: In constructor ‘Bar::Bar()’:
x.cpp:9:36: error: too many initializers for ‘Foo’
     Bar(void) : test{.a = 1, .b = 2} { }
                                    ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using GCC 4.9.1 and the following options:

```
-Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -pedantic
```

this is what you get:

```
prog.cc:7:5: warning: ISO C++ prohibits anonymous structs [-Wpedantic]
 };
 ^ 
prog.cc: In constructor 'Bar::Bar()':
prog.cc:11:21: warning: ISO C++ does not allow C99 designated initializers [-Wpedantic]
Bar(void) : test{.a = 1, .b = 2} { }
                ^ 
prog.cc:11:28: warning: ISO C++ does not allow C99 designated initializers [-Wpedantic]
Bar(void) : test{.a = 1, .b = 2} { }
                       ^ 
prog.cc:11:36: error: too many initializers for 'Foo'
Bar(void) : test{.a = 1, .b = 2} { }
                               ^
```

Using Clang 3.5.0 with the same options you get pretty much the same thing:

```
prog.cc:4:5: warning: anonymous structs are a GNU extension [-Wgnu-anonymous-struct]
    struct {
   ^ 
prog.cc:11:22: warning: designated initializers are a C99 feature [-Wc99-extensions] 
   Bar(void) : test{.a = 1, .b = 2} { }
                    ^~~~~~ 
prog.cc:11:30: warning: designated initializers are a C99 feature [-Wc99-extensions] 
   Bar(void) : test{.a = 1, .b = 2} { } 
                            ^~~~~~
```

In short, that's not valid C++11 code, for two reasons that are clearly indicated in the warning messages. Clang just happens to tolerate it and only issue the warnings, instead of an error. I'm not sure if it's worth debating 'who's right' in this case.